# Объединение дат в периоды по группе с несколькими столбцами

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть таблица А:

```
Id1 id2 Dt
--- --- ----------
a   a   01.01.2020
a   a   02.01.2020
a   a   03.01.2020
a   b   04.01.2020
a   b   05.01.2020
a   b   06.01.2020
a   b   07.01.2020
a   c   08.01.2020
a   c   09.01.2020
a   a   10.01.2020
a   a   11.01.2020
a   a   12.01.2020
b   a   01.02.2020
b   a   02.02.2020
b   a   03.02.2020
b   b   04.02.2020
b   b   05.02.2020
b   b   06.02.2020
b   b   07.02.2020
b   c   08.02.2020
b   c   09.02.2020
b   c   10.02.2020
b   d   11.02.2020
b   d   12.02.2020
b   d   13.02.2020
b   d   14.02.2020
```

И таблица Б:

```
Id1 id2 dt_start    dt_finish
--- --- ----------  ----------
a   a   01.01.2020  03.01.2020
a   b   04.01.2020  07.01.2020
a   c   08.01.2020  09.01.2020
a   a   10.01.2020  12.01.2020
b   a   01.02.2020  03.02.2020
b   b   04.02.2020  07.02.2020
b   c   08.02.2020  10.02.2020
b   d   11.02.2020  14.02.2020
```

Как можно из таблицы А получить таблицу Б?

Думал о рекурсивном запросе, о `GROUP BY`, но никак не могу найти путь решения.

[Данные для таблицы А](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=76be320a5d39b8254fdcf3f1d5946dc9).

Comment: Посмотрите на `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Dt) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTTION BY id1, id2 ORDER BY Dt)`... авось наведёт на мысль.

Comment: К сожалению, на мысль не наводит((

Comment: Под одной парой `id` `(a, a)` два разных диапазона, так и должно быть?

Comment: *на мысль не наводит* То есть даже не пробовал. Ибо результат даже слепой увидит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно так:

```sql
select id1, id2, min (dt) dtstart, max (dt) dtend from (
    select q.*, sum (case when prev != id1||id2 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by dt) grp
    from ( 
        select a.*, lag (id1||id2) over (order by dt) prev
        from A) q
) group by id1, id2, grp order by grp;
```

Результат как и ожидался:

```
ID1 ID2 DTSTART    DTEND     
--- --- ---------- ----------
a   a   01.01.2020 03.01.2020
a   b   04.01.2020 07.01.2020
a   c   08.01.2020 09.01.2020
a   a   10.01.2020 12.01.2020
b   a   01.02.2020 03.02.2020
b   b   04.02.2020 07.02.2020
b   c   08.02.2020 10.02.2020
b   d   11.02.2020 14.02.2020
```

Answer (score 1):

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT id1, id2, dt,
                     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY dt) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id1, id2 ORDER BY dt) group_number
              FROM test )
SELECT id1, 
       id2, 
       MIN(dt) dt_start, 
       MAX(dt) dt_finish
FROM cte
GROUP BY id1, id2, group_number
ORDER BY dt_start;
```

Comment: Не знаю, чем ТС не понравился tabibitosan, наверное надо было коротко поясненить решение. Ставлю плюс.